# Type of variables in a class: best programming practices

Tags: python, pep8

I define a class as below:

```
import numpy as np

class Vector:
    def __init__(self, v):
        self.v = v
```

I can create an instance of the class by doing the following:

```
p1 = np.array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0])

v1 = Vector(p1)
v2 = Vector(3)
```

My intention is that Vector always contains a vector in the 3D space. But, what is the proper way in python to make sure Vector will always be a 3-component vector?

Comment: You check it on `__init__` and raise a `ValueError` if you received a bad value.

Comment: @KlausD. Thanks. If you have time, and feel like it, please post a short answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in two ways, which can be used simultaneously. First, at runtime:

```
class Vector:
    def __init__(self, v):
        if not isinstance(v, np.ndarray) or v.shape != (3,):
            raise ValueError("vector must be 3-dimensional array")
        self.v = v
```

Checking types like this is pretty much a standard convention in python. However, with Python 3.5+ the `typing` module was added, which allows for so called "type hints", which can get statically analyzed by your IDE or linter:

```
class Vector:
    def __init__(self, v: np.ndarray[float, shape=(3,)]):
        self.v = v
```

However, type hinting is not yet fully implemented for numpy (the above syntax is preliminary), see [this tracking issue on GitHub](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/7370).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best way to do it, but for sure is one way. 
You can check with the following code:

```
import numpy as np
class Vector:
    def __init__(self, v):
        if isinstance(v, np.ndarray)  and v.size == 3:
            self.v = v
        else:
            raise ValueError('param is not an Array in the 3D space')
```